# Netplan try erroring out while making Static IP Change

Tags: networking, server, static-ip

All,

I would like to change the IP Address in my ***Ubuntu v18.04*** VM to Static IP address and I'm referring to these two articles to make the change:

**[How to configure networking with Netplan on Ubuntu | vitux.com](https://vitux.com/how-to-configure-networking-with-netplan-on-ubuntu/)**

**[How to Run Linux on Hyper-V | nakivo.com](https://www.nakivo.com/blog/run-linux-hyper-v/)**

However, when I try "NetPlan Try", I get an error. What mistake am I making?

```
network: 
  ethernets: 
    eth0: 
      addresses: 
        - 172.25.151.21/24
      dhcp: false
      gateway4: "192.168.151.17"
      nameservers: 
        addresses: 
          - "192.168.151.17"
          - "8.8.8.8"
  renderer: networkd
  version: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This netplan and DNS setup works on Ubuntu 19.10 and 20.04.  I'm adding a static IP as well as using dynamic IP assigned by router / DHCP.  My ISP intercepts DNS hence I use DNS over TLS (127.0.0.53) plus stubby so I can set docker to use this static IP for DNS.

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.202/24
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        use-dns: false
      dhcp6: true
      dhcp6-overrides:
        use-dns: false
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
  renderer: networkd
  version: 2
```

Putting it all together - place netplan cfg, apply it and DNS setup.  Are you copying / naming your netplan cfg correctly and applying it?

```
#!/bin/bash
# static IP - DNS servers and don't use gateway for DNS
# https://netplan.io/examples
# https://netplan.io/reference
sudo cp $HOME/mediacentre/bin/01-netcfg.yaml /etc/netplan/.
sudo netplan apply
# DNS over TLS
# https://www.internetsociety.org/blog/2018/12/dns-privacy-in-linux-systemd/
sudo cp $HOME/mediacentre/bin/resolved.conf /etc/systemd/.
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
# test it...
resolvectl query bbc.co.uk

# install stubby to do DNS over TLS
sudo apt-get install -y stubby
# use patched stubby config
sudo cp $HOME/mediacentre/bin/stubby.yml /etc/stubby/.
sudo systemctl restart stubby
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the static IP working by adding the correct virtual ethernet card (eth0)